# Laravel Server Side Event update global variable

Tags: php, laravel, variables, global, server-sent-events

I have an SSE event that selects last updates from table 'Newz' ad uses them to select from concerned **tables** the full data to stream it within the event.
The problem is I start with a global '$lastrec' = 0 (last record id) ,and try to update it during event which unfortunately doesn't update. What am doing or gettin' wrong ?
Grateful for any light.

Here a ~snap of my tables:

```
### table NEWZ ###############
    id          |   mdl     |
    11          | Todo      |
    12          | Memo      |
    13          | Todo      |
    14          | Todo      |
    15          | Memo      |
              ...
### large table TODOS ###############
id          |       dtm     |       rqr     | subject   |   ... |
11          |   2022-08-01  |   John Doe    |   ...     |   ... |
13          |   2022-08-02  |   John Doe    |   ...     |   ... |
14          |   2022-08-04  |   John Doe    |   ...     |   ... |


### large table MEMOS ###############
id          |       dtm     |       DEST    | REF       |   ... |
12          |   2022-08-01  |   PROD.       |   ...     |   ... |
15          |   2022-08-04  |   PROD.       |   ...     |   ... |
                            ...
```

Here the Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Response;
class NewzController extends Controller
{
    private $lastrec =0;    //(last record id starts with 0)        
    

    public function getDataStream($lang){

        $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse(function()  use ($lang){
            while(true) {
                $col=collect();
                
                $nwz = 'App\Models\Newz';
                $allnotif = $nwz::select('*')->where('id', '>' ,$this->lastrec)->get(); ///THIS IS THE PROBLEM $this->lastrec is always reset to 0 even after update
                
                foreach ($allnotif as $onenotif){ 
                    $mdl=$onenotif->mdl;                        
                    $zmodel = 'App\Models\\'.$mdl;
                    $notif = $zmodel::select('*')->where('id','=',$onenotif->id);
                    $col= $col->concat([$mdl => $notif]);
                    $this->lastrec = $onenotif->id;  // here I try to update $lastrec to last id value BUT unfortunately remains always 0
                }

                echo 'data: ' . json_encode(['lastrecord'=>$this->lastrec,'allNewz' => $col]). "\n\n"; //HERE I GET the right $lastrec but the start is always from 0       
                if( ob_get_level() > 0 ) ob_flush();
                flush();        
                if (connection_aborted()) { return;}                
                sleep(10);  
                
            }
            
        });
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
        $response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
        $response->headers->set('Cach-Control', 'no-cache');
        return $response;

    }
}
```

How I can get the $lastrec to get dynamically updated according to the new records inserted.

Comment: any help ?.. I really do appreciate any

Comment: you can use `$allnotif->last()->id` and remove `$lastrec`

Comment: tried to decrypt your words... no way to get the light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround solution:

the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Response;
class NewzController extends Controller
{
    //define the starting id ( $lastrec ) for $allnotifs in the route 
    //the user will set his own $lastrec

    public function getDataStream($lang,  $lastrec){

        $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse(function()  use ($lang){
            while(true) {
                $col=collect();
                
                $nwz = 'App\Models\Newz';
                $allnotif = $nwz::select('*')->where('id', '>' ,$lastrec)->get(); 
                
                foreach ($allnotif as $onenotif){ 
                    $mdl=$onenotif->mdl;                        
                    $zmodel = 'App\Models\\'.$mdl;
                    $notif = $zmodel::select('*')->where('id','=',$onenotif->id);
                    $col= $col->concat([$mdl => $notif]);
                    $this->lastrec = $onenotif->id;  
                }

                echo 'data: ' . json_encode(['lastrecord'=>$this->lastrec,'allNewz' => $col]). "\n\n";        
                if( ob_get_level() > 0 ) ob_flush();
                flush();        
                if (connection_aborted()) { return;}                
                sleep(10);  
                
            }
            
        });
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
        $response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
        $response->headers->set('Cach-Control', 'no-cache');
        return $response;

    }
}
```

The workaround happens in the js:

```
 var lastrec = storage.getItem('lastrec');
    //fire the streamEvent:
    lisTeningFunc(lastrec);

    const lisTeningFunc=async(last_save_did)=>{  
    if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
      var source = new EventSource(the_Defined_Route_For_The_SSE+'/'+last_save_did);      
      source.addEventListener('message', event => {
        let alldata = JSON.parse(event.data);        
        if (alldata.lastrec > lastrec){ 
        lastrec = alldata.lastrec;
        // handleNewz(alldata.allNewz) /*do what you want with the newz*/
          //close the EventSource
           source.close()
          //fire a new one with the new lastrec
          lisTeningFunc(lastrec)
        }       
        }, false);
          source.addEventListener('error', event => {
            if (event.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
                console.log('Event was closed');
            }
        }, false);
      } else {
        console.log("Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...");
      }
     }
```

So until someone suggest a solution to let the Laravel controller use a dynamic variable during SSE, the workaround solution is to reset the EventSource in the js-side and fire it again with the new lastrec.

Answer (score 2):

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Response;
class NewzController extends Controller
{
    public function getDataStream($lang){

        $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse(function()  use ($lang){
            while(true) {
                $col=collect();
                
                $nwz = 'App\Models\Newz';
                $allnotif = $nwz::select('*')->where('id', '>' ,$this->lastrec)->get(); 
                
                foreach ($allnotif as $onenotif){ 
                    $mdl=$onenotif->mdl;                        
                    $zmodel = 'App\Models\\'.$mdl;
                    $notif = $zmodel::select('*')->where('id','=',$onenotif->id);
                    $col= $col->concat([$mdl => $notif]);
                }
                $lastRecordId = $allnotif->last()->id;
                echo 'data: ' . json_encode(['lastrecord'=>$lastRecordId,'allNewz' => $col]). "\n\n";     
                if( ob_get_level() > 0 ) ob_flush();
                flush();        
                if (connection_aborted()) { return;}                
                sleep(10);  
                
            }
            
        });
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
        $response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
        $response->headers->set('Cach-Control', 'no-cache');
        return $response;

    }
}
```

Comment: First  thank you. Therefore, $lastRecordId = $allnotif->last()->id doesn't solve the problem. The last id I got it always in the  echo 'data: ' . json_encode(['lastrecord=>$this->lastrec. That's not the issue. The issue is how to take this $lastRecordId as a new start for $allnotif:  EX: In the beginning: $allnotifs selects all records > 0 and I have the last record right '15' now how to make $allnotifs selecting next time from 15 and not from  0. The problem is that the loop resets always to 0 and then I get all the records each time from 0.

Comment: please check again my question above I edited where exactly the problem is. Thank you

Comment: I guess there is no way to let the << $allnotif = $nwz::select('*')->where('id', '>' ,dynamic_Value)->get(); >> happens . Once the sse starts it keeps the first value